# 2 Factor Strong Authentication with Windows Live

Tags: web-services, security, authentication, openid, dotnetopenauth

I can see a video here
http://vimeo.com/2581892
of 2 Factor Strong Authentication with Windows Live.

How is this possible as I never heard Microsoft provide an API like Google here http://googleenterprise.blogspot.fr/2011/09/strong-authentication-to-protect.html ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say this for sure, but I suspect there isn't a way with Windows Live to use Yubikey.  The heading under the video you link to says: (emphasis added)

> This *simulation* of how adding the YubiKey to the Microsoft LiveID login experience *could* look.

The closest Windows Live has come to 2-factor authentication is that it has (at least in the past) allowed InfoCard authentication, but I haven't ever seen that advertised, and I haven't seen the option for quite some time so they may have pulled it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they have implemented 2-factor authentication on a number of services that relies on Live ID. These include access to the following:

- billing.microsoft.com
- xbox.com to buy points
- SkyDrive when remote to another computer

The two required factors are:

- Your Microsoft account and password
- A code sent to your alternate e-mail address or mobile phone that has been previously associated with your account.

(From http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/liveid-wlsecurity/two-factor-authentication-tfa-what-is-a-microsoft/79321863-cf01-44f3-a181-87f531c5129e)